# application of omitting types theorem in graph theory or some other discrete structure?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, model-theory

i'm looking for some applications of omitting types theorem in discrete structures like graphs...
for example something like end extension in PA....

Comment: What do you mean by "discrete structure"? What makes a graph more "discrete" than a model of PA?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example application: Suppose $G$ is a graph with the property that for any first-order formula $\varphi(x,y)$ in $2$ free variables, if there are any $a,b\in G$ such that $G\models\varphi(a,b)$, then there are some $a',b'\in G$ such that $G\models\varphi(a',b')$ and there is a path from $a'$ to $b'$. Then there is a connected graph which is elementarily equivalent to $G$.